# Referencing Name Property Using An Array

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a project that requires me to select worksheets depending on the value of a position in an array. I have populated `desArr()` (of type String) with values and `desArr(0)` contains the name of the sheet I want to reference. In order to avoid the problem with users changing the tab names and messing up the code, I am trying to reference the CodeName of the worksheet.

Usually, I would be able to do this:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Import.Name)
```

where `Import` is specified under the `(Name)` property in VB Editor. However, I would now like to reference that name variably, as in input depending on the value of `desArr(0)`. I tried doing the following but to no avail:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(desArr(0).Name)

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(desArr(0) & ".Name")
```

Does anyone have any idea on how to solve this problem?

Comment: ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(desArr(0))?

Comment: Thanks for your response! But that would just reference the tab name of the worksheet. So if one of my tabs in the workbook was "export" and desArr(0) contains "export" then it would work. What I wanted to achieve was to call the Name property of the worksheet which may or may not be the same as the tab name. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to collect the worksheet objects instead of their names?  If you had a worksheet object in the array instead of the name, you could call desArr(0).Name  Note that if you have set your worksheet appropriately, there is no need for the `ThisWorkbook.WorkSheets` part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use:

```
Import
```

That's the way to reference a sheet object without needing to know its `Name` property. Just use its variable/object name. The above is equivalent to, but much less convoluted than,

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Import.Name)
```

What you refer as the "CodeName" and the `(Name)` "property" isn't a property. It's just the name of the object variable. From what I can infer from your question, your sheet object is called `Import` so just use that.

---

EDIT:

It's hard to understand what you are asking; to clarify a bit:

If I understand correctly, you have a sheet called "Import", and you want to be able to guard against this scenario:

[image]

Ok, some user decided it was a good idea to rename the sheet. Note that this changed the sheet object's `Name` property's value to `"User-input crap"`. The `Name` property and the thing written in the tab are *always the same*; they're the same thing; they're linked one-to-one.

However, the sheet object itself is still called `Import`, or whatever it was earlier. (By default it is `Sheet1`, but maybe you changed that in the Properties window.) See:

[image]
Regardless of user-input crap, I can still say, for instance:

```
Import.Cells(1, 1).Value = "frog"
```

I can also say this, which is uselessly complicated but perfectly equivalent:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Import.Name).Cells(1, 1).Value = "frog"
```

I *could* also say this:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("User-input crap").Cells(1, 1).Value = "frog"
```

but for that I'd have to *know* what the user typed in the sheet tab, which I don't.

Comment: Thanks for the response! But I would like to reference the Name property because my code will fail if someone changes the worksheet tab names. With the Name property the user can't change it readily without first changing it via the VB editor. Also, I know the Name property for each worksheet, but I just don't know the syntax when the name is not typed in but is stored in an array desArr(0). Any thoughts?

Comment: The above should answer your question unambiguously.

Comment: Just to clarify, that would be what is posted in the tab name and can be changed right? So in this example, Import would be the name of the tab, but not necessarily the Name property of the sheet?

Comment: Import is just an example of a sheet name I could use, but ultimately that sheet name should be what is stored in desArr(0), but that's not the same as Sheets("Import"). Import in this case would be what appears on the tab name, and what I think you're suggesting, but if the user were to change Import to say Export, then Sheets("Import") would return an error.

Comment: Yes, I get what you're asking. I deal with the same thing all the time. What you are asking in this comment is already explained in my answer above. I suggest you try it for yourself. Perhaps experiment a bit.

Comment: That's an awesome depiction. Now using your visual example above, I'd like to use this:
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Import.Name).Cells(1, 1).Value = "frog" because if the user changed the name from "user-input crap" to something else, my code would fail. With that in mind, I have the name stored in desArr(0). and so I want to call it as such:
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets((here is where desArr(0) should return the name).Name).Cells(1, 1).Value = "frog", but that generates an error. This is what I was really getting at. I wanted to know if there was a way to do that. Sorry if it was confusing to you.

Comment: What I'm trying to get at is what if "Import" is now stored in desArr(0) and is variable depending on what desArr(0) is? I can't just type desArr(0).Name, because that would return an error.

Comment: That will *never* work. Forget about your array. You know your sheet is `Import`, and it will never change, so why store that in an array? Just use `Import` as a litteral.

Comment: I know my sheet is Import and that doesn't change, but I am going to be putting data into different sheets (Import, Export, Pending, Done) for instance depending on the data. So that array helps me make the decision as it contains the different indicators that it reads in from the data and that will determine which sheet to put it into. In summary, the array contains a variable of type string that I am trying to use to reference the sheet object so that I don

Comment: This has become a massive [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I won't write anymore on this thread. I suggest you post a new question describing clearly what you're trying to achieve.