# Moving Data and Refencing Sheet Object

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to automate a spreadsheet to transfer data from one sheet to another sheet depending on what the first 3 characters of the data is. So for example, for the data NDX 12/31/2012 P2600, I would like it to be placed in the NDX sheet. So I have an array (desArr()) that splits that data into different positions of the array, such that desArr(0) contains "NDX", desArr(1) contains "12/31/2012" and so on.

The part I am having trouble with is moving the data to the respective sheets. Specifically, I need a variable reference to these spreadsheets. For instant, take the NDX sheet. I know I can just do NDX.cells(1,1).Paste or Worksheets(NDX.Name).Cells(1,1).Paste and that would work, but what if I want to do that for multiple sheets? I could obviously use If statements to define each different instance, but I wanted to shorten my code. Hence, I am trying to make the reference to the sheet objects variable, i.e. desArr(0).Name, but it returns with an error (which I understand why). Anyone with suggestions on how to achieve this? I know one solution is to just use the name property of the worksheet, but I wanted to avoid the chance of my code failing if someone changed the name of the sheets.

So perhaps like:

```
Dim desArr() As String, desInfo As String, opType As String
Dim rNum As Long, cNum As Long, i As Long
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim sortRng As Range, findRng As Range
Dim j As Integer 'Throw away after testing
Dim test As String 'Throw away after testing
Dim k As Integer 'Throw away after testing 

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets(Import.Name)

With ws
rNum = .Range("C1048576").End(xlUp).Row
cNum = 6 'Number of used columns starting from left
Set sortRng = .Range(.Cells(3, 2), .Cells(rNum, cNum))

'Sort range according to Type and Description
sortRng.Sort _
    Key1:=.Range("B1"), _
    Key2:=.Range("C1")

'Apply conditional formatting
    With sortRng.Columns(2)
        .FormatConditions.AddUniqueValues
        .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
        .FormatConditions(1).DupeUnique = xlDuplicate

        With sortRng.Columns(2).FormatConditions(1)
            .Interior.PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Interior.Color = 13551615
            .Interior.TintAndShade = 0
            .StopIfTrue = False
        End With

    End With

 For i = 0 To (rNum - 2)
    With sortRng.Cells(i + 1, 2)
    If .DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = "13551615" Then
        j = 0
        While (.Value = .Offset(j + 1, 0).Value And .Offset(0, 1).Value = .Offset(j + 1, 1).Value)
            j = j + 1
        Wend

        If (j <> 0) Then 'There are duplicates

        End If
    End If

    'Converting the description to format used for classification
    If .Offset(0, -1) = "Ext Option" Then
            desArr = Split(.Value, " ")
        If Not (Left(.Value, 3) = "SX5" Or Left(.Value, 3) = "UKX") Then

            'check if it's a call or put
            If Left(desArr(3), 1) = "C" Then
                opType = "Call"

            ElseIf Left(desArr(3), 1) = "P" Then
                opType = "Put"

            Else
                opType = "N/A"

            End If

            desInfo = Format(desArr(2), "mmmdd") & " " & Right(Trim(desArr(3)), Len(Trim(desArr(3))) - 1) & " " & opType

        Else
            'check if it's a call or put
            If Left(desArr(2), 1) = "C" Then
                opType = "Call"

            ElseIf Left(desArr(2), 1) = "P" Then
                opType = "Put"

            Else
                opType = "N/A"

            End If

            desInfo = Format(desArr(1), "mmmdd") & " " & Right(Trim(desArr(2)), Len(Trim(desArr(2))) - 1) & " " & opType

        End If

    End If

    End With
Next i

 End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

End Sub

Except that NDX would have to be variable as which worksheet to move the data to depends on the data.

Comment: It's kind of unclear what you're asking...

Comment: It would help to show more of your existing code.

Comment: `With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(desArr(0))` should do it

Comment: For background, see the [OP's earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24085574/referencing-name-property-using-an-array) and the agonizing discussion that ensued.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the codename property of the worksheets. If you use NDX.Cells(1,1), NDX is the codename of the sheet. simply search all worksheets, e.g.:

```
Function GetWorksheet(byval withCodename as String) as Worksheet
    Dim sheetVar as Worksheet
    For each sheetVar in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If sheetVar.CodeName = withCodename Then
            Set GetWorksheet = sheetVar
        End if
    Next
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You could:

### Prevent user from renaming sheets

You wrote: "I wanted to avoid the chance of my code failing if someone changed the name of the sheets."

Well, the user can't do this: 
[image]

If you protect the workbook. You can do this manually in the ribbon (Review > Changes > Protect workbook), or programmatically like this:

```
ThisWorkbook.Protect 'optionally, add a password -- see documentation for Protect
```

This will entirely prevent the user from changing sheet names.

Comment: Yes I am aware of that, but I don't want to force the user to not change it if they need to or to have them edit the code everytime they want to change it, which becomes tedious. Worst comes to worst, I'll try that.